# Android pre-launch report x86 usage

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, firebase-test-lab, prelaunch

We've built an app using Flutter and uploaded the Android app bundle to the Google Play Store. The pre-launch report showed an error when running the device on a virtual Google Pixel 2 device with an x86 ABI.

Other people have experienced the same error as me (see [#83596](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596)) and it seems to be related to the fact that Flutter [does not support building for x86](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures)

The [Google docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en-GB) for pre-launch reports state that the test devices used when making pre-launch reports are all ARM devices, so why was our app even tested on an x86 device?

[image: Google docs screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems that the Docs have been update as of 3 Aug 2023 and now read: [image]

So using a ABI filter in `app/build.gradle` as per:

```
defaultConfig {
  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a','x86_64' 
}
```

should do the trick.